# How to persist entity with multiple composite keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Using Hibernate 5.1.10. I have a Company with a list of Departments and Employees, and I want to place employees in the different departments. Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="company_id")
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Department> departments;

    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeeId.class)
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    public static class EmployeeId implements Serializable {
        private long id;
        private Company company;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {...}

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_id")
    private long id;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Company company;
    private String name;

    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(DepartmendId.class)
public class Department implements Serializable {
    public static class DepartmendId implements Serializable {
        private long id;
        private Company company;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {...}

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="department_id")
    private long id;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Company company;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<DepartmentEmployee> employees;

    ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(DepartmentEmployeeId.class)
public class DepartmentEmployee implements Serializable {
    public static class DepartmentEmployeeId implements Serializable {
        private Department department;
        private Employee employee;

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {...}

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="department_id", updatable=false, insertable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="company_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    })
    private Department department;
    @Id
    @OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="employee_id", updatable=false, insertable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="company_id", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    })
    private Employee employee;
    private int rating;

    ...
}
```

This creates the following tables:

```
create table Company (
    company_id bigint generated by default as identity,
    name varchar(255),
    primary key (company_id)
)

create table Department (
    department_id bigint not null,
    name varchar(255),
    company_id bigint not null,
    primary key (company_id, department_id)
)

create table Employee (
    employee_id bigint not null,
    name varchar(255),
    company_id bigint not null,
    primary key (company_id, employee_id)
)

create table DepartmentEmployee (
    rating integer not null,
    employee_id bigint not null,
    company_id bigint not null,
    department_id bigint not null,
    primary key (department_id, company_id, employee_id)
)
```

So far so good. I can create a company with departments and employees and persist it without any problem. However, as soon as I try to add some of the employees to a department, I get the following error:

```
26-03-2019 09:30:29 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (main) SQL Error: 90008, SQLState: 90008
26-03-2019 09:30:29 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (main) Invalid value "5" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-196]
```

From what I've been able to gather so far, is that there is some confusion in the `DepartmentEmployeeId` class, where hibernate thinks there are 4 ID columns, and not 3. However I have not found any good solutions. How can I get Hibernate to understand that `company_id` should only be used once in the IdClass? Rewriting the data model by using a single ID per table is not an option for me.

Comment: Don't use updatable=false, insertable=false. Foreign key needs to be inserted, later it may be updated also.

Comment: There is nothing in your data model that prevents a `DepartmentEmployee`'s Department and Employee from being from different `Company`s; so they cannot share the `company_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on @EmbededId used with @MapsId https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MapsId